# Log odds ratio as dependent variable in regression

Tags: regression, modeling, odds-ratio

I have data with binary outputs of success/failure as the result of undergoing a high and low temperature treatment after being subjected to treatments involving combinations of several other variables. In other words, I have a series of contingency tables across a set of variables. I am interested in whether the comparative effect of the temperature treatment changes across the series of other variables, and whether or not it stays approximately the same.

Based on this, I think it makes sense to model the log odds ratio of the outcomes of the two temperature treatments for each combination of other explanatory variables. Based on some sources I've found and looking at the data, the log odds ratio seems to be approximately normally distributed, and it seems like this would work well under a regression modeling approach.

However, I have not seen many examples of regression analyses that include the log odds ratio as a dependent variable. Is there any reason for this? Is there a better approach that would allow me to answer this set of questions with my data?

Hope this makes sense, and thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try logistic regression (with the binary dependent variable) directly?

Comment: I guess my thinking is that I want to discern how the other variables affect the outcome of the temperature trial, and I'm not sure of the best way to do that. If I just modeled the dependent binary variable directly, I would be included the temperature trial is a predictor, but I'm trying to gain a sense of how the other variables influence the effect of the temperature trial.

Comment: Can you give more details please as an edit to the post! How many 2x2 contingency tables? Design? How many observations in total? It does make sense to plot the estimated log odds ratios against the other predictors, please show us those plots! See [the secret weapon](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/03/07/the_secret_weap/).